# How to facilitate chatting in a Drupal site?

Tags: chat, drupal

Consider a [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) site used by either (or both) anonymous users and/or registered (and logged in) users. The required functionality is that it should be possible to perform these kinds of chat-like interactions:

- Chat with the website owners/administrators.
- Chat with other (logged in) users.

Pretty sure that "There is a (contributed) module for it!", no? Which one(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Live chatting with anonymous users

Have a look at the [My Live Chat](https://www.drupal.org/project/mylivechat) module. Some details about it (from its project page):

> This module adds the necessary script to the footer of ones site for prompting users to chat via My Live Chat.
>
> My LiveChat is a fast, high performance and most user-friendly live chat solution. My LiveChat allows you to live chat with website visitors, monitor site traffic, and analyze visitors' web activities, including their search engine and keyword usage. Free version is also available.

To see it at work in a (real) [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) website, head over to [this website](http://www.permantiermotors.be/).

## Modules to facilitate messaging between users

#### DrupalChat

The [DrupalChat](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalchat) module allows visitors of your Drupal site to chat with each other privately or together in a public chatroom. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> This module enables sites to provide online support for their products/services, and thereby increases user engagement. Also, it is useful for social networking sites, forums, blogs, etc. It logs the user conversations so that they can be later viewed in message inbox.

#### Privatemsg

The [Privatemsg](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module allows your site's visitors to send private messages to each other. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Perfect for community oriented sites, such as forums and social networking sites. Many additional features are available as separate modules.

#### Chat Room

The [Chat Room](https://www.drupal.org/project/chatroom) module enables chat rooms to be set up on Drupal sites. No additional software is required.  Some more details about this module (from its [Community Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/625484)):

> ... uses AJAX to update chats without page reloads. Chatrooms and chats are nodes, providing easy access with many other modules, such as Views, CCK and Organic Groups. The module features chat in pop-up windows, invitations and private chats.
>
> Chatroom is aimed primarily at tight integration with Drupal, not at being a highly scalable IRC or XMPP style solution.